# Multiple assignment by if statement

Tags: go

It is possible to execute multiple assignment by if condition, like the following code?

```
func SendEmail(url, email string) (string, error) {

    genUri := buildUri()
    if err := setRedisIdentity(genUri, email); err != nil; genUrl, err := buildActivateUrl(url, genUri);  {
        return "", err
    }  

    return "test", nil

}
```

Comment: Doesn't that look a little hard to decipher ?

Comment: I don't think so. Your code is a bit hard to read, too. Maybe you want to split it up into multiple if-statements.

Comment: ok, I think it would be better for read too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.  Only one 'simple statement' is permitted at the beginning of an if-statement, per the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements).

The [recommended](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#if) approach is multiple tests which might return an error, so I think you want something like:

```
func SendEmail(url, email string) (string, error) {
    genUri := buildUri()
    if err := setRedisIdentity(genUri, email); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }  
    if genUrl, err := buildActivateUrl(url, genUri); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return "test", nil
}
```

Answer (score 25):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func a(int) int { return 7 }

func b(int) int { return 42 }

func main() {
    if x, y := a(1), b(2); x > 0 && x < y {
        fmt.Println("sometimes")
    }
    fmt.Println("always")
}
```

Output:

```
sometimes
always
```