# multi-value functions and if statements

Tags: go

This tests if a map contains a certain value:

```
_, ok := myMap["foo"]
```

Is there a way to use this check in an if statement, so that I can chain multiple tests together?

```
if ("foo" in map1) || ("bar" in map2) {
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be roughly what you're looking for.

```
if _, ok := myMap["foo"]; ok {
    //do stuff
}
```

<s>You should be able to chain multiple statements in the parentheses so that you can have multiple checks at a time.</s>

```
if (_, okfoo := myMap["foo"]; _, okbar := myMap["bar"]; okfoo || okbar) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Only that it looks horrible... ;-) I was hoping for a single expression (per map) that checks the return value directly and saves the assignment altogether. 
Thanks for answering anyways!

Comment: I completely agree that is looks horrible. Sorry about that.

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of (myMap["foo"])[1] would work?

Comment: I don't believe `(_, ok := myMap["foo"]; ok == true)` is valid syntax; You need to get rid of the parenthesis, or better yet, do `_, ok := myMap["foo"]; ok`.

Comment: Also the 2nd snippet still won't work : ["Only one 'simple statement' is permitted at the beginning of an if-statement"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25284952/2998271)

Comment: @Akavall, \@har07, Sorry about that, I was unaware only one statement was allowed. Thank you for correcting me.